# select count(*) and count(*) where column is not null in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables employee and stores employee will have certain stores assigned his duty is to fill the address of the stores in stores table i have around 40 k stores in db

I want get count of all stores and count of stores where address is filled.

```
$sql = "select count(*) from stores";
```

the above query will return count of all stors how to get count of address filled stores in same query instead of

```
$sql = "select count(*) from stores where address is not null"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be new to SQL.  You can easily count the non-NULL values of a column using `COUNT()`:

```
select count(*), count(address)
from stores;
```

Best wishes on learning SQL.

Answer (score 1):

use `sum()` in place of `count()`

Try that:

```
 select count(*) as count_all , SUM(if(address is not null, 1, 0)) AS count2 
 from stores
```

Comment: No need for this complication. `COUNT(column)` is all one needs.